# Upload de Arquivo Nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer

Tô quebrando a cabeça aqui para tentar fazer o upload de imagens com o Nodejs mas tá sendo "freud".

Estou desenvolvendo uma api onde nela terá acesso por parte de três domínios.
Então, a estrutura da minha api está basicamente:

```
public
src
  company
    ... *.js
    routes.js
  client
    ... *.js
    routes.js
  admin
    ... *.js
    routes.js
  routes
    routes.js
  app.js
```

Em cada diretório destinado ao seu respectivo domínio, eu tenho o arquivo de rotas chamando seus controllers. Um exemplo, as rotas acessadas pelo domínio company:

```
router.get('/c/:id', auth.authorize, controller.getData);
router.post('/login', controller.login);
router.post('/register', controller.create);
router.get('/activate/:code', controller.checkActivationCode);
router.put('/update/:id/:section', auth.authorize, controller.update);
router.get('/get_business_hours', auth.authorize, controller.getBusinessHours);
router.post('/logo', auth.authorize, imgUpload);

module.exports = router;
```

No diretório routes, eu pego essas rotas de cada domínio e condenso num único arquivo, ficando assim:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        version: "1.0.0"
    });
});

const companyRoutes = require('../company/routes/company');

app.use('/', router);
app.use('/api/company/', companyRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

Como eu vou ter muitas rotas já que serão três domínios acessando, subdividi dessa maneira. Mas agora que vem o problema, na rota post('/logo'), onde faz a chamada do multer para armazenar a imagem, não é feito o upload do arquivo.

No arquivo (controller) do upload da imagem está assim:

```
const multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/public/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('logo')

module.exports = upload;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beleza?

É porque o *diskStorage* utiliza o endereço físico do sistema para armazenar os arquivos em disco na opção de destino. Ou seja, se você colocar só uma barra antes da string no *destination* ele vai considerar que você quer armazenar o arquivo na raiz do seu sistema. Por exemplo, se você estiver rodando seu localhost num Windows e passar `cb(null, '/public/')` ou `cb(null, '/public')` (barra-public) ele vai tentar gravar na unidade *C:*. Especificamente em *C:\public*

Então as opções que você pode utilizar são:

- `cb(null, './public')` (ponto-barra-public)
- `cb(null, 'public')`
- `cb(null, 'public/')`

Todas essas opções consideram que o diretório raiz será em relação a pasta do projeto que está rodando em seu servidor local. Então se o seu localhost é em relação à pasta *C:\Projetos\Site* o multer vai salvar em *C:\Projetos\Site\public* mesmo que ele seja chamado em *C:\Projetos\Site\src\company\routes\company*.